# Removing An Event From Calendario.js

Tags: jquery, html

All,

I'm currently using Calendario.js, and things are working pretty well. However, I'm trying to figure out the method to removing events.

I've already figured out how to add events through a dictionary that you pass into the cal.setData() function. However, when I remove an event from the dictionary and call the same cal.setData() function, it doesn't successfully remove it. Does anyone know anyway to do this? The documentation is pretty sparse.

HTML

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{%          static'main/Calendario/js/jquery.calendario.js' %}"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'main/Calendario/js/modernizr.custom.63321.js' %}"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'main/Calendario/css/calendar.css' %}" />
<link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'main/Calendario/css/custom_2.css' %}" />
<link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'main/lightbox/lightbox.css' %}" />

    <div class='container'>
        <div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2'>
            <div class="custom-calendar-wrap">
                <div id="custom-inner" class="custom-inner">
                    <div class="custom-header clearfix">
                        <nav>
                            <span id="custom-prev" class="custom-prev"></span>
                            <span id="custom-next" class="custom-next"></span>
                        </nav>
                        <h2 id="custom-month" class="custom-month"></h2>
                        <h3 id="custom-year" class="custom-year"></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div id="calendar" class="fc-calendar-container"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
cal = $calendar.calendario( {
            onDayClick : function( $el, $contentEl, dateProperties ) {
                if(dateProperties.day.length==1){
                    dateProperties.day = 0 + dateProperties.day;
                }
                if(dateProperties.month.toString().length==1){
                    dateProperties.month = 0 + dateProperties.month.toString();
                }

                if($el.hasClass('fc-content')){

                    $el.removeClass('fc-content');

                    console.log($el);
                    delete codropsEvents[dateProperties.month + '-' + dateProperties.day + '-' + dateProperties.year];
                }
                else{
                    codropsEvents[dateProperties.month + '-' + dateProperties.day + '-' + dateProperties.year]='<a href="#"></a>'
                    console.log(codropsEvents);
                    cal.setData(codropsEvents);
                }

                if( $contentEl.length > 0 ) {
                    showEvents( $contentEl, dateProperties );
                }

            },
            caldata : codropsEvents,
            displayWeekAbbr : true
        } ),
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy if you were to use the latest version of Calendario - https://github.com/deviprsd21/Calendario, `$('#calendar').calendario('setData', data, clearData);`, if you pass true in clearData all the previous data will be cleared and replaced by the new one.